# first git pull and git push do not work

Tags: git, github

I am just a github newbie

I have tried to update with git several times and got succeeded once.

However, everything just went wrong when I tried to review this process by deleting all my repositories, related files, local and remote branches.Because they looked so messy.

So my situation is:

I first created a repository in my github and after trying everything I have searched on internet, like:

```
git init

git branch --track gitbook master
```

I still get stuck here. While I push and pull, I get nothing changed except that at certain point those .md s in my github repository were created in my local file, which is manual.

now..

```
Walter: gitbook wangxuefei$ git branch -a

*master

remotes/gitbook/master

Awlter:gitbook wangxuefei$ git remote -v

gitbook https://github.com/Awlter/supermanual (fetch)

gitbook https://github.com/Awlter/supermanual (push)

Awlter:gitbook wangxuefei$ git pull

Already up-to-date.

Awlter:gitbook wangxuefei$ git push





warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in

Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message

and maintain the traditional behavior, use:



  git config --global push.default matching



To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:



  git config --global push.default simple



When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches

to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.



Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'

behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding

remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.



See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.

(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode

'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)
```

Everything up-to-date

so what can I do next?

Comment: Check out http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/ and https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/ for some beginner guides to using git and github.

Comment: it works! wow, just a simple  git add * and git commit... Lots of thanks, Josh!